# Разработка приложений на языке C в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio

После компилирования на Windows 7 в Visual Studio 2017 простого приложения:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

В той же Windows 7 выполняется на ура. А вот в Windows XP говорит что приложение не является Win32 приложением. Я так понимаю VS прописывает свои зависимости от Net Framework в исполняемый файл, который требуется чтоб был установлен везде где запуститься приложение? Т.е. так же как и для C#. Если это так то есть ли решение отбросить такие предложения, чтоб все зависимости он вписывал в exe?

Comment: Скорее всего вы просто скомпилировали код в 64-битный исполняемый файл, и пытаетесь его запустить под 32-битной системой (Windows XP).

Comment: @insolor все верно стоит x86

Answer (score 1):

Там в свойствах проекта, где-то в районе генеральных настроек есть опция, 
`установить платформу Toolset` - выберете Compatible Windows XP, 
подробнее [на msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx)

Comment: Такой вопрос. Там в абзаце "C++ runtime support" указано что "For these operating systems, the minimum supported versions are Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3) for x86, Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) for x64, and Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 (SP2) for both x86 and x64." Требуется минимум SP3. Это нечего страшного и C не коснется или все же не запуститься на SP2 и SP1?

Comment: Написанному обычно надо верить :) и ХР ниже сервис пака 2 найти я думаю не реально.